# How to do a Case Insensitive search on Azure DocumentDb?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

is it possible to perform a case insensitive search on DocumnetDb?

Let's say I have a record with 'name' key and value as "Timbaktu"

This will work:

```
select * from json j where j.name  = "Timbaktu"
```

This wont:

```
select * from json j where j.name  = "timbaktu"
```

So how do yo do a case insensitive search?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 38):

There are two ways to do this. 1. use the built-in LOWER/UPPER function, for example,

```
select * from json j where LOWER(j.name) = 'timbaktu'
```

This will require a scan though. Another more efficient way is to store a "canonicalized" form e.g. lowercase and use that for querying. For example, the JSON would be

```
{ name: "Timbaktu", nameLowerCase: "timbaktu" }
```

Then use it for querying like:

```
select * from json j WHERE j.nameLowerCase = "timbaktu"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Aravind, the LOWER does not work. The query will return an empty result when the provided string is converted to LOWER and the actual string in the db is not.

Comment: Codehelp, on my query, I'm calling LOWER on the string in the DB, right? I'm assuming the string passed in is lower, but you can instead, do something like LOWER(j.name) = LOWER('timbaktu')

Comment: Aravind, it works when the passed in string, be it LOWER or any other matches what's in the Db. My question is do we have something like 'COLLATE' as in SQL?

Comment: There is no equivalent to COLLATE in DocumentDB. Strings are represented in UTF-8 only (per the JSON standard).

Comment: Azure Cosmos DB now supports case-insensitive queries through the functions `Contains`, `EndsWith`, `StartsWith` and `StringsEquals`.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/new-string-function-performance-improvements-and-case-insensitive-search/

Comment: @Martin4ndersen it indeed looks like it, but there is no support in the SDK yet so for most of the users it can't be used until then

Comment: Using LOWER in a call when trying to return results, such as SELECT * from c WHERE CONTAINS(LOWER(c.firstName), "fred") is massively inefficient and slow.

Comment: @AravindKrishnaR. FYI the email in your profile doesn't work. Comes back as Recipient address rejected: access denied

Answer (score 8):

Cosmos recently added a case-insensitive option for string functions:

> You now have an option to make these string comparisons
> case-insensitive: Contains, EndsWith, StringEquals, and StartsWith.
> and Significant performance improvements have been realized for these
> string system functions. Each of these four string system functions
> now benefit from an index and will therefore have much lower latency
> and request unit (RU) consumption.

[Announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/caseinsensitive-string-functions-with-azure-cosmos-db-now-available/)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is an ancient case, I just want to provide a workaround.

You could use [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf) in azure cosmos db.

***udf:***

```
function userDefinedFunction(str){
    return str .toLowerCase();
}
```

And use below sql to query results:

```
SELECT c.firstName FROM c where udf.lowerConvert(c.firstName) = udf.lowerConvert('John')
```

[image]

Comment: Just wondering - is this a better approach than using the built-in functions (LOWER/UPPER) as mentioned above?