# Case insensitive search in arrays for CosmosDB / DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Lets say I have these documents in my CosmosDB. (DocumentDB API, .NET SDK)

```
{
    // partition key of the collection
    "userId" : "0000-0000-0000-0000",
    "emailAddresses": [
        "someaddress@somedomain.com", "Another.Address@someotherdomain.com"
    ]
    // some more fields
}
```

I now need to find out if I have a document for a given email address. However, I need the query to be case insensitive.

There are ways to search case insensitive on a field (they do a full scan however):

[How to do a Case Insensitive search on Azure DocumentDb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512806/how-to-do-a-case-insensitive-search-on-azure-documentdb)

```
select * from json j where LOWER(j.name) = 'timbaktu'
e => e.Id.ToLower() == key.ToLower()
```

These do not work for arrays. Is there an alternative way? A user defined function looks like it could help.

I am mainly looking for a temporary low-effort solution to support the scenario (I have multiple collections like this). I probably need to switch to a data structure like this at some point:

```
{
    "userId" : "0000-0000-0000-0000",
    // Option A
    "emailAddresses": [
        {
            "displayName": "someaddress@somedomain.com",
            "normalizedName" : "someaddress@somedomain.com"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Another.Address@someotherdomain.com",
            "normalizedName" : "another.address@someotherdomain.com"
        }
    ],
    // Option B
    "emailAddressesNormalized": {
        "someaddress@somedomain.com", "another.address@someotherdomain.com"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my production database already contains documents that would need to be updated to support the new structure.
My production collections contain only 100s of these items, so I am even tempted to just get all items and do the comparison in memory on the client.

Comment: You have already given yourself 3 usable solutions: If you can change the schema, update those 100 documents. If not, scan those 100s of docs. What else do you expect in answers?

Comment: I can't scan for array properties(server-side). Thats what the question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance matters then you should consider one of the normalization solution you have proposed yourself in question. Then you could index the normalized field and get results without doing a full scan.

If for some reason you really don't want to retouch the documents then perhaps the feature you are missing is simple join?

Example query which will do case-insensitive search from within array with a scan:

```
SELECT c FROM c
join email in c.emailAddresses
where lower(email) = lower('ANOTHER.ADDRESS@someotherdomain.com')
```

You can find more examples about joining from [Getting started with SQL commands in Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query#GettingStarted).

Note that where-criteria in given example cannot use an index, so consider using it only along another more selective (indexed) criteria.

Comment: Works! Was using Array_Contains the whole time, not sure how I missed this. Now I only need to do transfer this into "SDK format", but either way this looks good.

Comment: FYI, this SQL-like syntax already is .NET SDK-edible format via `DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery` method. See example code in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query#ExecutingSqlQueries.

Comment: Yeah but linq would be even nicer