# How can i search case insensitive contains with LINQ and Azure DocumentDb?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

How can I perform a case insensitive search with contains on DocumnetDb?
I'm using LINQ expression with IDocumentClient.

Here is an example of string comparision in LINQ:

```
u => u.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchParam.ToLower())
```

but I'm aware this is a full table scan.

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a Case Insensitive search on Azure DocumentDb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512806/how-to-do-a-case-insensitive-search-on-azure-documentdb)

Comment: It's not duplicated because I mentioned about LINQ not LOWER/UPPER function in DocumentDB

Comment: What do you think the `u.Name.ToLower()` would be translated to for documentDB execution? Leaving chosen syntax and question cosmetics aside, both problem and the solution are identical to the duplicate candidate.

Comment: @ImrePühvel I don't think they are the same. Using LINQ or SQL in C# code is a design choice so the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: I think your query shall be working now

Comment: Before you enter into an evil early optimization, test your query and find out the RUs it consumes when executed against your DB. I'm currently using that query and I haven't found any issues with it, performance or financially wise.

As you can see, this is what the generated SQL i get when i run that query.

"SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE CONTAINS(LOWER(root[\"name\"][\"name\"]), \"searchParam\")"}