# How to compare ignoring case with IN keyword

Tags: sql, azure, scope, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In Cosmos Scope / SQL how to compare a column country with a list of value ignoring case.

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_name IN ("aLpHa", "BetA", "GamMa")
```

Comment: It is odd that a column "country" would have the name `student_name`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a Case Insensitive search on Azure DocumentDb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512806/how-to-do-a-case-insensitive-search-on-azure-documentdb)

Answer (score 3):

The following query should work in cosmosdb

```
select * from json j where LOWER(j.student_name) IN ("alpha", "beta", "gamma")
```

[image]

You can have a [`UDF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/user-defined-functions) as well,

udf:

```
function convertLower(str){
    return str .toLowerCase();
}
```

and use it as

```
SELECT * FROM c where udf.lowerConvert(c.student_name) IN ("alpha", "beta", "gamma")
```

Comment: As mentioned in the other question (and Aravind's answer) I linked to as duplicate, `lower()` is not efficient, as it will end up scanning an entire partition (or all of the collection, if you enable a cross-partition query), since it completely bypasses any indexing.

Comment: Documents are also showing it should work. This is not even running in iScope. What are the tools you are using? Sorry if it is silly. I am new to Cosmos environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lower()`:

`SELECT * FROM student WHERE lower(student_name) IN ("alpha", "beta", "gamma")`

Or alternatively, user `upper()` respectively.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can do the same thing in cosmos db?

Comment: @pcbabu I'm not familiar with it, but if it doesn't work you can also try using `ilike` for comparison (it's same as `like` only case-insensitive): `SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_name ilike "alpha"`

Comment: Also, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30513004/1057429) you can use `lower()`

Comment: FYI `lower()` results in a partition (or collection) scan, since it can't use indexes on the properties being searched. More details in the answer to the question I linked as duplicate.